# Mapping Video streaming URL with SPRING MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, ffmpeg, video-streaming

I'm developping a site for video streamings.

My application server works with spring MVC (front is managed by angular).

I have another server, that provides stream flux (uses ffmpeg).

Today I have direct URL to my video server, something like that : 
http://myvideos_server.com/videos/video.m3u8

this URL is detectable client side....

Is it any technic do not provide my videos streaming URL directly ? Is it possible mapping videos stream URLs with Spring MVC ?

Comment: I guess you can map  http://myvideos_server.com/videos/video to  http://myvideos_server.com/videos/video.m3u8video.m3u8 in your controller and execute video.m3u8 and proces the rest.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Can you explain ?

Comment: Assuming any request for `http://myvideos_server.com/videos/video.m3u8` is redirected to `/video` in your controller like this `@GetMapping("/video") public String m3u8Videos(){//your code here to play with .m3u8 }`. Now you can do what ever with .m3u8